# Making my toggle Navbar be above other content

Tags: html, css

I've built my own toggle navbar in my React-Project.
when it's on, it doesn't block the content beneath it.
so all the user can see is a mess.
I've tried z-index in my CSS but sadly it didn't help..
this is the css code, there is more but it's for the design so i didn't add it, its alot but if it is required i will add it.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1028px){
    .navRight{
        flex-direction: column;
        height: auto;
    }
    .NavItem{
            width: 100%;
            border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #6bbe92;
    }
    .toggleMenuBut{
        display: block;
    }
    p{
        text-align: center; 
        margin:auto;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .NavContainer{
        margin-bottom: 200px;
    }
    .inlineLogout{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .isToggled{
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div className="NavContainer">
   {screenWidth>1028 ? <>
   <div className="navRight">
      {user ? 
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/content'} className="linkP vertical-center" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
         <p>Videos</p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      :null}
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/recommendation'} className="linkP vertical-center" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
         <p>Recommendation</p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/about'} className="linkP vertical-center" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
         <p>About</p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/'} className="linkP vertical-center" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
         <p>Home</p>
         </Link>
      </div>
   </div>
   {user ?  <>
   <div className="navLeft">
      <div className="NavItem" onClick={onLogout}>
         <Link to={'/'} className="linkP vertical-center" >
         <p>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRightFromBracket}/>
            Log Out
         </p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="NavItem" >
         <Link to={'/acc'} className="linkP vertical-center" >
         <p>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser}/>
            Profile
         </p>
         </Link>
      </div>
   </div>
   </> : <>
   <div className="navLeft">
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/login'} className="linkP vertical-center">
         <p>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRightFromBracket} />
            Log In
         </p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/register'} className="linkP vertical-center">
         <p>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquareArrowUpRight} />
            Register
         </p>
         </Link>
      </div>
   </div>
   </>}
   </>: <>
   <button onClick={toggleNav} className="toggleMenuBut">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} size={"3x"} />
   </button>
   {toggleMenu ? 
   <div className="isToggled">
      {user ?
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/content'} className="linkP vertical-center"  onClick={handleOnClick} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
         <p>Videos</p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      :null}
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/recommendation'} className="linkP vertical-center"  onClick={handleOnClick} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
         <p>Recommendation</p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/about'} className="linkP vertical-center"  onClick={handleOnClick} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
         <p>About</p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/'} className="linkP vertical-center"  onClick={handleOnClick} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
         <p>Home</p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      {user ?  <>
      <div className='NavItem' onClick={onLogout}>
         <p>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRightFromBracket}/>
            Log Out
         </p>
      </div>
      <div className='NavItem'>
         <Link to={'/acc'} className="linkP vertical-center" onClick={handleOnClick} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
         <p>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser}/>
            Profile
         </p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      </> : <>
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/login'} className="linkP vertical-center" onClick={handleOnClick}>
         <p>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRightFromBracket}/>
            Log In
         </p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="NavItem">
         <Link to={'/register'} className="linkP vertical-center" onClick={handleOnClick}>
         <p>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquareArrowUpRight} />
            Register
         </p>
         </Link>
      </div>
      </>}
   </div>
   : null}
   </>}
</div>
```

adding also an image:

[image]

recommendation's page:

```
<div>
        <center>
        <h1 className="h1Rec">Our recommendation</h1>
        <div className="pDiv" id="one"><p class="pRec">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
        <div className="carouselDiv">
        <Carousel width={'80%'} infiniteLoop={'true'} useKeyboardArrows={'true'} showThumbs={0} showStatus={0}>
        {Images.map(renderCarouselItem)}
        </Carousel>
        </div>
        </center>
    </div>
```

in addition recommendation's CSS:

```
.RecComment{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.RecBut{
    background-color: #6bbe92;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px;
    margin: auto 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;

}

.recDiv{
    margin:225px 50px;
}

.h1Rec{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.pRec{
    line-height: 100%;
}

.pDiv{
    width: 80%;
    border-style: dotted;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#one {
    border:solid 5px white;
    border-radius: 255px 50px 255px 50px/50px 225px 50px 255px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
  }

  .carsProp{
      width: 80%;
  }
  
  .carouselDiv{
    height: 600px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
   .recDiv{
       height: 300px;
   }
   .h1Rec{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.carouselDiv{
    height: 300px;
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Salem, Can you add your html as well? Also did you took out "Our recommendation" text out of normal flow if yes then that might be the reason for this happening

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, added my html, can you explain pls about the flow u mentioned?

Comment: you have added code showing only the toggle Navbar component but you aren't showing how the component or element with "Our recommendation" seems to be have been styled or working as siblings elements

Comment: so what part of my code you need? css of recommendation? or html of the other pages? all the pages have the same issue

Comment: If all pages have same issue then I believe its the CSS for recommendation which is causing this. I need the part where "our recommendation" and the navbar are being handled. Otherwise if you Can you make a minimum reproducible example of this that would be fine too?

Comment: Hi again, I edited once again the code, you can see above, in addition I meant that all pages get stucked in the navbar while I open it, so I think the problem might be in navbar... maybe any attribute I forgot. Thanks again for helping!

Comment: Can you add a codesandbox of this and reproduce it and share the link? I will try and take a look

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-raman-fuvp06?file=/src/Rec.jsx 
tell me if you need any more parts..

Comment: When I asked you to add a sandbox its expected to be working. So, that if not me someone else can also take a look and help you. I can't be of any help unless you provide me the means to help you. You can refer this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems before using a toogle navbar, but mine was pop up dialog form for login and register in Asp.Net web form.
All I did was create a fixed div to cover the whole page and set its opacity to 0.7 as the overlay for my login popup dialog.
Then I created a fixed div for my popup dialog and centered it on my page.
So I have my popup login and a semi opaque overlay.
This can also help you create a semi opaque overlay to cover the whole Page, your menu as a fixed div with 100℅ height and 30℅ width. So your menu won't interfere with your HTML body items. Remember to set the z-index of the menu above than that of the overlay and body.

Comment: I'll try, as but if I change it to fix and 30% width, won't it be on just a part of the screen?
I want it all over the width, and if I set the height to "auto" isn't it like inherit which means 100% of parent's height?

Comment: If you want it set to cover your screen no need to add the overlay, just create your menu make the width and height 100℅ not auto, z-index to be above that of your body.

Comment: Hi, even if I would set it to 100% width and height, it would get stucked with the other content...

Comment: Please explain I don't understand you...how would it get stuck with other content?

Comment: If you set the width of your menu to 100℅ and the z-index to be above all other page content, it would cover your whole page without items overlapping your menu...I'm not on my system if was I would have shown you a sample code.

Comment: I tried it without setting the width and height to 100%, it has so much influence if I set it to 100% width? the z-index didn't work alone..